# how to show an image received from listbox sent as a parameter in the next page

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I am building an app for windows phone 7 where i am collecting a few data from web service and displaying those data in a listbox. Now on clicking an item in the listbox i am navigating it to another page where i am showing the complete details.
The code to display the item in the listbox is:

```
public class Newss
{
    public string News_Title { get; set; }
    public string News_Description { get; set; }
    public string Date_Start { get; set; }
    public string image_path { get; set; }
    public BitmapImage ImageBind{get;set;}
}

public News()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    KejriwalService.aapSoapClient client = new KejriwalService.aapSoapClient();
    client.getarvindNewsCompleted += new EventHandler<KejriwalService.getarvindNewsCompletedEventArgs>(client_getarvindNewsCompleted);
    client.getarvindNewsAsync();

    progressName.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
}

void client_getarvindNewsCompleted(object sender, KejriwalService.getarvindNewsCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    string result = e.Result.ToString();
    List<Newss> listData = new List<Newss>();
    XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(result);

    progressName.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;

    foreach (var location in doc.Descendants("UserDetails"))          
    {
        Newss data = new Newss();

        data.News_Title = location.Element("News_Title").Value;
        data.News_Description = location.Element("News_Description").Value;
        data.Date_Start = location.Element("Date_Start").Value;
        data.image_path = location.Element("image_path").Value;
        data.ImageBind = new BitmapImage(new Uri( @"http://political-leader.vzons.com/ArvindKejriwal/images/uploaded/"+data.image_path, UriKind.Absolute));

        listData.Add(data);
    }

    listBox1.ItemsSource = listData;
}
```

The way i am sending the data to the next page is:

```
private void listBox1_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // If selected index is -1 (no selection) do nothing

    if (listBox1.SelectedIndex == -1)
        return;

    Newss news = listBox1.SelectedItem as Newss;
    NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/NewsDetails.xaml?News_Title=" + news.News_Title + "&News_Description=" + news.News_Description +"&Date_Start=" +news.Date_Start + "&image_path=" + news.image_path, UriKind.Relative));

    // Reset selected index to -1 (no selection)
    listBox1.SelectedIndex = -1;
}
```

Now i am able to display in the next page the news_title, news_description, date_start but not able to display the image. My code in that page is:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
    var imagePath = "";
    var dateStart = "";
    var newsTitle = "";
    var newsDescription = "";

    if (this.NavigationContext.QueryString.ContainsKey("Date_Start"))
    {
        //if it is available, get parameter value
        dateStart = NavigationContext.QueryString["Date_Start"];
        date.Text = dateStart;
    }

    if (this.NavigationContext.QueryString.ContainsKey("News_Title"))
    {
        //if it is available, get parameter value
        newsTitle = NavigationContext.QueryString["News_Title"];
        title.Text = newsTitle;
    }

    if (this.NavigationContext.QueryString.ContainsKey("News_Description"))
    {
        //if it is available, get parameter value
        newsDescription = NavigationContext.QueryString["News_Description"];

        description.Text = newsDescription;
    }            
}
```

Please someone help me to display the image in the NewsDetails page for the xaml given below

My xaml for displaying the image is:

```
<Image Height="201" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="45,113,0,0" Name="newsimage" Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="368" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the way you display the image in the previous page, I think something like this will work :

```
var imagePath = "";
if (this.NavigationContext.QueryString.ContainsKey("image_path"))
{
    imagePath = NavigationContext.QueryString["image_path"];
    newsimage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri( @"http://political-leader.vzons.com/ArvindKejriwal/images/uploaded/"+imagePath, UriKind.Absolute));
}
```

I assumed that "image_path" parameter passed in Uri contains value of `data.image_path` from  previous page.